# Error in react-native-admob, Can someone help me?

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I'm trying to add admob to my project, but when installed, my project can't install on my phone, does anyone know what it might be?

error bellow

> Configure project :react-native-admob
> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
> It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
> WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3)> Resolve dependencies of :react-native-screens:debugCompileClasspath
> for Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.3.
> Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
> To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle
> Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-admob:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
40 actionable tasks: 38 executed, 2 up-to-date
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\55419\Desktop\MyApp2\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesMana
ger.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\55419\Desktop\MyApp2\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesMana
ger.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
C:\Users\55419\Desktop\MyApp2\node_modules\react-native-admob\android\src\main\java\com\sbugert\rnadmob\RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdMod
ule.java:20: error: RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method onRewardedVideoCompleted()
in RewardedVideoAdListener
public class RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-admob:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to
  get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/envi
ronment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: What version of react-native-admob you have in package.json  ?

Comment: version 1.3.2 in package.json

Answer (score 1):

In node-modules/react-native-admob/android/build.gradle

replace ====> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+.'

With ====> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0'

Hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Install the beta version instead...

`yarn add react-native-admob@next`

Don't forget to delete your node-modules folder, and clean your build folder *as a precaution*